# What is the correct way to use signed URL for resumable uploads to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a signed URL in my App Engine code and pass it to the client to make the initial POST call to get the resumable upload location, following the following advice from the documentation:

> Performing a resumable upload in a region where it wasn't initiated can
>   cause slow uploads. To avoid this, you can have the initial POST
>   request constructed and signed by the server, but then give the signed
>   URL to the client so that the upload is initiated from their location.

However, when a client makes a POST call to the signed URL, this call results in error 401, which tells me that Cloud Storage expects an authorization header.

This is how my signed URL looks like:

https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=resumable&name=fileName&GoogleAccessId=xxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1463628862&Signature=IZNU%2B2ApaUlogY9CR%2B4DC09WKkIpeZLeuqzrudyxA0nETH7Wpr4x8aRZTZj%2BGOriCDL8JfnoyAFhY1XqMG7VU3VPliu7LXoDSvuH0Cjaoz5lefNs80HpneAHI7HpAX2Uv2Lr57ZwbXM3EoegGiTcJb3ck51VH0%2FxTWSnqxlJsgQzo9%2BYKVhkHBzFn29k7k76qsGhN91g5CfTtSKtfa%2FiYwCffoB%2BctIdULwKF7yMugNkLKAfqxrWRXVAmrzXUK9njGTOQqfcvAtq4jJ23Aflo6ETmDKghZuZNLqoHs5umEhFRC1eFGd%2Be10RDRON%2F1ysXahWawSx4YOE9bEZXPKNtQ%3D%3D

I use the same code on the App Engine side to generate signed URLs for downloads and they work just fine.

Is this the correct way to assemble the URL for the initial POST call? Is there something else causing this error?

EDIT

Code to generate URL:

```
long expiration = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 + 60;
String unsigned = stringToSign(expiration, gsKey, "POST");
String signature = sign(unsigned);
return new StringBuilder("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/")
        .append(BUCKET)
        .append("/o?uploadType=resumable&name=")
        .append(gsKey)
        .append("&GoogleAccessId=")
        .append(identityService.getServiceAccountName())
        .append("&Expires=")
        .append(expiration)
        .append("&Signature=")
        .append(URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8"))
        .toString();

private static String stringToSign(final long expiration, String gsKey, String httpVerb) {
    String contentType = "";
    String contentMD5 = "";
    String canonicalizedExtensionHeaders = "";
    String canonicalizedResource = "/" + BUCKET + "/" + gsKey;
    String stringToSign = httpVerb + "\n" +
            contentMD5 + "\n" +
            contentType + "\n" + 
            expiration + "\n" + 
            canonicalizedExtensionHeaders + "\n" +
            canonicalizedResource;
    return stringToSign;
}

private static String sign(final String stringToSign) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    SigningResult signingResult = identityService.signForApp(stringToSign.getBytes());
    String encodedSignature = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(signingResult.getSignature(), false), "UTF-8");
    return encodedSignature;
}
```

Comment: Could you replace the URL with the code that generates the URL and signature? It's probably easier to tell what's wrong from the code than from the output.

Comment: Do you specify `x-goog-resumable:start` header in the POST request? Also the [gsutil utility docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl#options) say that the method is `RESUMABLE` for resumable uploads. Maybe this helps?

Comment: Scratch that, looks like those two things are only important if you use the XML API. However the JSON Api says you'll have to provide an Authorization header. So you may have to initiate the upload as authorized user, while the subsequent PUT requests do not need to be authorized. Also I'm confused whether you can sign the URL you're signing since that is an API URL and not a cloud storage url, which would look somthing like storage.google.com/bucket/file.

Comment: also checkout the [signurl code of gsutil](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/348457d49fb3ba54a098a532330d07b5c4de69a6/gslib/commands/signurl.py). Looks like that is the XML API after all and it's also the one you use or should be using. Therefor the method should be RESUMABLE and you also need to specify he headers they they do in the gsutil code.